# with flask, in the handler for a POST request containing a file upload, how do I read that data?

Tags: python, forms, opencv, flask

I need to get an image from an input type file from an HTML form and then crop it with opencv, but I don't know how to read it, can someone help me?

HTML:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="update-doc" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3">
    <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupFile01">UPLOAD</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="pic" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" id="inputGroupFile01">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-5 shadow">UPLOAD</button>
</form
```

> 

**Python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, session, flash
import cv2
profileimg = request.files['pic']
img = cv2.imread(profileimg)
```

Comment: flask? django? something else? -- what is this object? is it a string containing a file path? or is it a file-like object you can read from?

Comment: Is working with Python Flask

Answer (score 1):

this is what worked for me:

```
from urllib import request
import cv2
profileimg = request.form['pic']
img = cv2.imread(profileimg)
crop_img = img[y_begin:height, x_begin:width]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I forgot to tell you that I'm using python flask so the request is from Python Flask. Is there a way to read the image with OpenCV if I'm getting the image with request of Flask?